# Guided wavelength for a transmission line using MWO TXLINE

Tags: transmission-line

Is it possible to find the guided wavelength for a transmission line using Microwave Office's TXLINE?

I am trying to find the guided wavelength \$λ_g\$ for a transmission line with a characteristic impedance \$Z_0\$.

I think there must be a way to do this using TXLINE but I can't see anywhere to calculate this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Microwaves101](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/waveguide-mathematics), the guided wavelength is,

> the distance between two equal phase planes along the waveguide.

I haven't used TXLine, but based on the image you showed, you will probably get this by inputting 360 for the electrical length on the input side and reading off the physical length on the output side.

Comment: I thought the physical length was the actual length of the material, not the wavelength?

Comment: It's the actual length to get the electrical length you specified on the input side. If you ask for an electrical length of 360 degrees, you're asking for the length to be equal to one wavelength.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense thanks

Comment: Like I said, I haven't used TXLINE, so test this with some cases where you already know the correct answer before trusting it completely.